# After changing my List vom ng-repeat to collection-repeat ng-click is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I had a List like this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="itemClick({{item[0]}})">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

now I changed it to:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in items" ng-click="itemClick({{item[0]}})">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

while having the following code in my controller:

```
$scope.itemClick = function (index) {
    // index is undefined
};
```

before making the change from `ng-repeat` to `collection-repeat` all works fine. Now I get `index` as `undefined`.

Whats wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Here are my items:

```
var items = {
    [1, "foo"],
    [2, "bar"], 
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show me your `items` object values?

Comment: did you read my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{}}` Iterpolation won't work inside `ng-click`, you can directly mention variable name that will directly gets fetched from their respective variable.

> `ngClick` clearly states that it accepts an expression:
>   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick

**Markup**

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in items" ng-click="itemClick(item[0])">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in items" ng-click="itemClick(item[0])">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

if you want only index value, then try this below

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in items" ng-click="itemClick($index)">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{}}` won't work inside `ng-click`, just `del{{}}`, use `itemClick(item[0])`.